# Difference in PayPal IPN between notify url and return url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I know this sounds very basic , but while working with PayPal first time I have this question in my mind .
I have gone through Google searching but did not get a proper response differentiating between "PayPal IPN and notify url or return url". Any help regarding this will be appreciable.

Also if possible I need to know what is the advantages and their functional differentiation as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notify Url: The URL to which PayPal posts information about the
transaction via Instant Payment Notification. Must be URL-
encoded. Its an optional field have maximum 256 characters
length.

Return url: The URL to which the customer's browser is returned
after completing the payment; for example, a URL on your site
that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page.
Default: customer is taken to the PayPal website. Optional
rm Return method GET or POST: the FORM METHOD used to send data
to the URL specified by the return variable after payment
completion.

Comment: I just implemented paypal in my website: the return url is a script on my server which gets transaction details and stores what I need in the database.  Does IPN is designed to more or less the same thing or it has some more peculiar use??

Answer (score 4):

IPN is more of an process or the name of a method for used to facilitate/validate the checkout process.

The notify URL is the listener script that PayPal posts back to with information regarding details of the transaction at hand. This will be a script you have placed on your server that helps PayPal validate the details of the buyer and the prices of your products before writing it all into the books and calling it a day.

The return URL is the address URL that the buyer will be redirected back to once the transaction is complete. Again this is a script on your web server that is something of a "thank you" or "transaction successful" message to them.